# How do I move a DB from localhost to a live server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I built a database and website using Xampp which allows me to use and test php and a database which is hosted on localhost. I now want to move this to a live server. I have moved the website to a live server using 123-reg. How do I move the database?

I have tried exporting the phpmyadmin db and placing the sql file in my live directory, not sure of the next steps. Unlike other hosting websites, 123-reg does not seemingly have a phpmyadmin option as a web tool. It does however have something called "MariaDBDatabases". Can I use this somehow?

Comment: Quick search gave me https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/hosting/how-do-i-import-a-mysql-database/

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is the correct way. You just have to export your database on localhost. Then import in your live database given in link

Go to export option. click on **GO**.
Make a new database. 
And Import in that

Answer (score 0):

Yes off course.

Generally, hosting providers don't provide insecure links like `http://anything.com/phpmyadmin` as DB access location. 
Instead of that, they provide UI in control panel ( dashboard ) to access all the features.

It ensures the added security to avoid your custom database from unauthorised exploitations.

I don't know the UI features of your host provider exactly, but as you said, click over `MariaDBDatabases`, create a new DB (Copy that), create a new User (Copy that along with the password).

Now click over DB just created, I hope it will redirect you to phpMyAdmin.
There you can import your SQL.
Now all you have to do is, change the DB Credentials in your project.